# Por que alguns services em angular usam cifrão ("$") no início?

Tags: angularjs

Eu utilizei algumas bibliotecas escritas para AngularJS onde os Services estavam sempre escritos com um `$` no início.

Por exemplo, no Angular Material temos o serviço `$mdDialog`, e no Angular Bootstrap temos o `$uibModal`.

Já outras bibliotecas eu vi que não usaram o `$`. Como no modulo `ngFileUpload`, temos o service `Upload`.

Até então eu achava que era obrigatório usar `$`.

Mas eu gostaria de saber se esse `$` trata-se de alguma padronização ou recomendação do Angular.

Isso serve para fazer diferença entre Services e Factory, ou alguma coisa do tipo?

Comment: Porque fica mais bonito.

Comment: Ou seria para usar o mesmo nome para diretiva e serviço? Pois usando o `$` quebraria-se o conflito, né?

Comment: Para ficar parecendo php.

Comment: Para ficar parecendo jQuery.

Comment: Para ficar parecendo [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/).

Comment: Cês não valem um cifrão...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em algumas circunstâncias o Angular ignora variáveis ​​prefixadas com o sinal `$` (cifrão, ou *dollar sign*):

- Filtros json não geram conteúdo de saída;
- Quando usando a diretiva `{{}}` o Angular não mostrará as propriedades ​​iniciadas por $, apenas as propriedades públicas;
- Além disso, `watch()` não dispara para propriedades que  comecem com `$` - estas serão ignoradas quando o observador estiver sendo inicializado;
- `Angular.equals()` ignora as chaves prefixadas com `$`.

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648794/1845714)

Comment: Muito importante essa informação. Então o `$` não é só firula.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters correto, existe funcionalidade por trás do uso.